# What are some interesting problems in the intersection of Diophantine Approx and Algebraic Geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, diophantine-approximation, research, euler-mascheroni-constant

I am a first year graduate student and I am eager to work on irrationality/transcendental proofs of specific numbers like Euler's constant gamma. Because backgrounds for Elliptic Curves include very much of Algebraic Geometry but there is no professor working on Transcendental NT, Analytic NT or Elliptic Curves, so I was wondering is there a subject in the intersection of irrationality/transcendental proofs of specific numbers (or more generally Diophantine approx) with Algebraic Geometry so that I can write a proposal for the professor who works in Algebraic Geometry? I couldn't find any on the Internet.

Comment: The title is helped from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103243/what-are-some-interesting-problems-in-the-intersection-of-algebraic-number-theor

Comment: Do you have an advisor? This is a question more suitable to ask them.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao, No! The process of selecting an advisor in this country's universities is that either 1- I am interested in some professor's area of interest then he/she will provide a specific subject to begin or 2- If I want to suggest a subject not in the areas of interests of some professor, I **myself** need to find a nearby subject and write a proposal for that to persuade him/her.

Comment: Hi L.G! There are many intersections indeed. For instance, the analytic subgroup theorem involves a lot of intricate algebraic geometry and estimates on auxiliary polynomials (see this talk for an introduction: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6j1DPZBMNBS_cOOVcxEHJDGwxhqz7Q6/view?usp=sharing). Also, the theory of periods provides a lot of examples of numbers which are conjecturally transcendental (see this book for an introduction: http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/arithgeom/preprints/buch-alt/buch-v6.pdf).

Comment: Simulposted to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186026/what-are-some-interesting-problems-in-the-intersection-of-diophantine-approx-and  without notice to either site. Don't do that!

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Why? I didn't know that if it's not legal on StackExchange. –

Comment: Gerry wanted to say that you should mention the cross-post on both sides. Don't do that = don't cross-post without notice.